# MySql text localization

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to localize the result of my query. To do this I have:

- the table `Show`, with `id` and some other information;
- the table `ShowName` with `idShow`, `name`, `lang` (for each show there are multiple `showName`s where `Show.id` = `ShowName.idShow`)

My query is now, and works correctly:

```
select Show.*,
(SELECT name FROM ShowName 
    WHERE Show.id=ShowName.idShow 
    ORDER BY FIELD(lang,'$userPreferredLanguage','en','it','es','fr','de','pt','da','he','pl','nl','hu','no','sl', 'fi','sv','tr','cs','hr', 'el','ru','zh','ja','ko') 
    LIMIT 0,1) as name,
from Show
```

Now, the question is: is there a way to speed up things a little bit? The query as is takes about 3secs, 2 of them are used to compute the inner `SELECT`. I tried with `INNER JOIN`, but I couldn't figure out how to omit the second select.
PS: note that `ShowName` may not have all the localizations, so I need to use the `FIELD` function instead of a simple `WHERE lang = '$userPreferredLanguage'`.

Thaks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind to add your table structures? The `ORDER BY FIELD` might be one reason why this takes so long. I understand, that you might not have a translation for all words in all languages, but does it really make sense to display Korean when you don't have Danish available? Usually you have your default language, e.g. english, which you can fall-back to if you don't have the term in the requested language.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on `ShowName(idShow)`?

That would help.  A better index would be:  `ShowName(IdShow, name, lang)`, because all the column references in the subquery can be satisfied by the index.

It also might be faster to do an explicit join once you have the index:

```
select Show.*,
       (SELECT name
        FROM ShowName join
             (select 'en' as lang, 1 as priority union all
              select 'it', 2 union all
              . . .
             ) lp
             on showname.lang = lp.lang
        WHERE Show.id=ShowName.idShow 
        ORDER BY lp.priority 
        LIMIT 0, 1
       ) as name
from Show
```